# My IMAP email account is recognized as Office 365 and then I can't configure it as IMAP account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, android, imap

I have an Android phone with the latest version of MS Office including Outlook installed.

When I try to setup my email account user@mydomain.com in Outlook then the app "thinks" it's an Office 365 account and asks me to sign in to that account. But it is an IMAP Account.

[image]

So then I click on "Back" and I select IMAP and then I see the form to fill in the details of my IMAP account like server names, etc. I fill everything in but I always get the error message "Log-In Error  Please check your email and password and try again." I tried many times to make sure my spelling is correct, with and without port numbers, it just does not work!

Now I setup a test email account on the same email server with the email address abc@mydomain.com. And surprisingly Outlook recognizes this as an IMAP account and brings me directly to the form to fill in the IMAP details. I do this and it works.

[image]

**Now the big question is what can I do to make my main account user@mydomain.com work. For the test account I used the same password and all the other settings are 100% the same, except the username.**

Until now I did not uninstall Office on my phone. If necessary I will do that but often applications "remember" old settings so I am not so sure if uninstalling and installing it again will make any difference.

Please let me know if you have any idea how I can solve this crazy problem.

Comment: Check your settings against [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-up-email-on-other-internet-capable-phones-and-tablets-775748a1-0075-40fd-b630-1d2a84be081a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and let us know.

Answer (score 2):

I just deleted Outlook completely and reinstalled it.
After that my user@mydomain.com account was still detected as an Office 365 account. But after I clicked back and then IMAP and then filled in the form it works now.

What is still annoying is that it is not possible to edit any of the input settings after the account is setup. I read somewhere else on the internet that if someone wants to change any setting MS suggests to delete the account and set it up again...

This is one answer which works. If anybody else has an answer which does not require the reinstallation of Outlook pleased post it.